# Java print List and arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, list

I was hoping someone could help me out with a small problem I am having in java. I have a List and an ArrayList that I would like to output to a file with the first element of each, printed next to one another. Here is what I have so far:

```
List<String> uniqueList = new ArrayList<String>(dupMap.values());
for(String unique:uniqueList){
   out.write(unique + "\r");
}
ArrayList<Integer>subtr=new ArrayList<Integer>();
out.write("The number: " + subtr + "\r");
```

This results in this output:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
The number: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

But I would rather it be like this:

```
A The number: 1
B The number: 2
```

...etc.

I am not really sure where to start on how to get the output format like that. I tried putting both sets of values into arrays but I just ended up confusing myself... Which is how I ended up here. Any help would be super appreciated.

Comment: ... are you sure `\r` is right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
String br = System.getProperty("line.separator");
for (int i = 0, n = Math.min(uniqueList.size(), subtr.size()); i < n; i++)
    out.write(uniqueList.get(i) + " The number: " + subtr.get(i) + br);
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought that it wouldn't be too complicated but I kept getting lost. Do you mind explaining Math.min() as it is used here for me?

Comment: @User Sure! it's just a safeguard in case one of the lists is longer than the other, in this way we won't try to access an index outside of the shorter list. If both lists are guaranteed to always have the same size, then `n = uniqueList.size()` would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> uniqueList = new ArrayList<String>(dupMap.values());
ArrayList<Integer>subtr=new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < uniqueList.size(); i++){
   out.write(uniqueList.get(i) + "\r");
   out.write("The number: " + subtr.get(i) + "\n");
}
```

**NOTE**: This assumes that both lists have the same number of elements. If they are not, you would iterate to `Math.min(uniqueList.size(), subtr.size())`.

Comment: That will give you an exception, if `subtr.length() < uniqueList.length()`

Comment: @Baz Yes. But the question assumes that they have the same number of elements.

Comment: They indeed should be the same size, I forgot to specify that. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
int maxLength = Math.min(uniqueList.size(), subtr.size());
for(int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
{
    out.print(uniqueList.get(i) + " The number: " + subtr.get(i) + "\r");
}
```

Comment: You should remove `"\r"` and replace with new line or `println`.

Comment: @Desolator Could you explain why?

Comment: Some environments don't accept `\r` as a new line specifier, `\r` is the carriage return, not new line. It would be replaced with `\n`. However, best of all, using `println` is the most portable.

Comment: @Desolator Fair enough, but the OP used `"\r"`, so I guess it's only appropriate, if I provide code, that does the same as his.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
List<String> uniqueList = new ArrayList<String>(dupMap.values());
ArrayList<Integer> subtr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int length = Math.min(uniqueList.size(), substr.size());
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   out.write(uniqueList.get(i) + " The number: " + substr.get(i) + "\r");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The efficient way is to maintain a `HashMap` with `uniqueList` as keys and `subtr` as values. Then iterate over a map.

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < uniqueList.size(); i++){
    map.put(key, subtr.get(i));
}
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    out.println(entry.getKey() + " The Number : " + entry.getValue());
}
```